# Laravel i have save data in location table multiple id in one field

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel i  have save data in location table multiple id in    json form in database . Now i want to where condition on that where  which is  not working.

```
$data = $request->all();

  $loopdata = $data['data']['d_category'];
  $loop = $data['data'];
     for ($i =0 ; $i < count($loopdata); $i++) {

         $request['d_category'] = $loop['d_category'][$i];
         $request['belt_no'] = $loop['belt_no'][$i];
         $request['e_name'] = $loop['e_name'][$i];
         $request['assign_date'] = $loop['assign_date'][$i];
         $request['location'] = $loop['location'][$i];
         $a = json_decode($loop['location'][$i]);
       $u = User::where('belt_no', $loop['belt_no'][$i])->whereIn('location',  $a)->get()->toArray();
       }
```

Comment: Can you add some examples of your code?

Comment: Are you looking for [JSON Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#json-where-clauses)?

Comment: Yes i tried but getting error , Mysql query error